# C++ Root library - TF1.GetRandom() function not working properly

Tags: c++, root-framework

I am using the GetRandom() function for a TF1 type ([Root library](https://root.cern.ch/doc/master/classTF1.html)) function and can't get it to work properly.
**Both** with this example:

```
TF1* f1 = new TF1("f1", "30+x", 0.2*M_PI, 0.5*M_PI);
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        cout << f1->GetRandom(0.2*M_PI, 0.5*M_PI) << endl;
    }
```

and with this example:

```
TF1* f1 = new TF1("f1", "cos(x)", 0.2*M_PI, 0.5*M_PI);
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        cout << f1->GetRandom(0.2*M_PI, 0.5*M_PI) << endl;
    }
```

I am getting outputs like this:

```
1.31227
0.933722
0.915021
1.52884
0.83633
1.55911
0.73908
```

Which do not match the values I expected. In the first example I expected it to output numbers between 30.6 and 31.8, and the second one between 0 and 0.8.
Did I misinterpret what the GetRandom function does or is something else wrong?

Comment: What is `TF1`? Some `TensorFlow` type or something you wrote?

Comment: @KorelK it is class part of the root library, from CERN. https://root.cern.ch/doc/master/classTF1.html

Comment: Pay attention you tagged this question with `root`, which refers here to unix root user, and to this Root library.

Comment: @KorelK I have added the correct tag. Honestly I am surprised that the unix user `root` got priority for the tag. It is not really useful as a tag.

Comment: I couldn't find a proper fix to this issue so I went around it and found other ways to do it, so it no longer has any urgency to me, although it is still an unresolved issue.

Comment: @guia4273 I don't use ROOT myself, but the documentation states that `GetRandom` returns random values with a distribution specified by the curve. It does not say that a random `x` value is plugged into the formula.

Comment: I understand now, I believe you are correct @walnut. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

As @walnut has said, GetRandom returns returns random values with a distribution specified by the curve, not values of the corresponding formula to random "x" values. Problem solved

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `f1->GetRandom` returns values in the range `0.2*M_PI, 0.5*M_PI`. The density of each value is described by the function `f1`: if you ask `GetRandom` for enough values, their relative occurrence will match the shape of `f1`.